# How to use a jar in Unity3D?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have a jar library that i created.
It can be integrated in any android app and it works like this:

```
String token="<SOME_TOKEN>";
DeviceIdentifier edDevice = new DeviceIdentifier(
                            this.getApplicationContext(),token);
edDevice.update();
```

DeviceIdentifier class os a class in the jar.

now i want to make that jar work with Unity3d, 
i searched the web and couldn't find anything

what is the correct way to integrate it?

Comment: In case you haven't seen them: manual pages for [native code plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html#AndroidPlugins), or [Android plugins in particular](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).

Comment: but what about the "this.getApplicationContext()" ? can i get it on unity?

Answer (score 0):

Getting files from a jar file needs to be accessed from the WWW class and written to a readable path, Here is a code example that allows you to copy files out of jar. Then use your IO framework to access those files.

This particular code accesses the jar file created from the streaming assets folder. If you have a custom jar file you may need to alter the path that the WWW points to.

```
public static IEnumerator ExtractFileFromJar(string filename, string filepath)
{
    WWW fileFromJar = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + filename);
    yield return fileFromJar;
    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, fileFromJar.bytes);
}
```